# Creating files using c#, like an evernote

Tags: c#

I currently am making a UI for a note keeper and was just going to preview documents etc, but i was wondering what file type i would need to create if instead i wanted to do things like tag the file etc, preferably in c#, basically make my own evernote, how do these programs store the notes?

Comment: What do you mean by tagging them? What tag would you add to a file? and should the users be able to see these tags?

Comment: yes, tagging so then i can search it, think evernote, not quite sure how it works but ive googled so much and am no where closer to an answer, thanks

Comment: Bear with me since making the answer will take some time, but I have two ideas you might like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how to directly tag the file, but you could create your own system to do it. I mentioned two ways to do it:

1. The first way is to format the note's / file's contents so that there are two parts, the tags and the actual text. When the program loads the note / file, it seperates the tags and the text. This has the downside that the program have to load the whole file to just find the tags.
2. The second way is to have a database with the filename and it's associated tags. In this way the program doesn't have to load the whole file just to find the tags.

## The first way

In this solution you need to format your files in a specific way

```
<Tags>
tag1,tag2,tag3
</Tags>
<Text>
The text you 
want in here
</Text>
```

By setting up the file like this, the program can separate the tags from the text. To load it's tags you'd need this code:

```
public List<string> GetTags(string filePath)
{
    string fileContents;

    // read the file if it exists
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    else
        return null;

    // Find the place where "</Tags>" is located
    int tagEnd = fileContents.IndexOf("</Tags>");
        
    // Get the tags
    string tagString = fileContents.Substring(6, tagEnd - 6).Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""); // 6 comes from the length of "<Tags>"

    return tagString.Split(',').ToList();
}
```

Then to get the text you'd need this:

```
public string GetText(string filePath)
{
    string fileContents;

    // read the file if it exists
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    else
        return null;

    // Find the place where the text content begins
    int textStart = fileContents.IndexOf("<Text>") + 6 + Environment.NewLine.Length; // The length on newLine is neccecary because the line shift after "<Text>" shall NOT be included in the text content

    // Find the place where the text content ends
    int textEnd = fileContents.LastIndexOf("</Text>");

    return fileContents.Substring(textStart, textEnd - textStart - Environment.NewLine.Length); // The length again to NOT include a line shift added earlier by code
}
```

Then I'll let you find out how you do the rest.

## The second way

In this solution you have a database file over all your files and their associated tags. This database file would look like this:

```
[filename]:[tags]
file.txt:tag1, tag2, tag3
file2.txt:tag4, tag5, tag6
```

The program will then read the file name and the tags in this way:

```
public static void LoadDatabase(string databasePath)
{
    string[] fileContents;

    // End process if database doesn't exist
    if (File.Exists(databasePath))
        return;

    fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(databasePath); // Read all lines seperately and put them into an array

    foreach (string str in fileContents)
    {
        string fileName = str.Split(':')[0]; // Get the filename
        string tags = str.Split(':')[1]; // Get the tags

        // Do what you must with the information
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it has, def. gave me the needed info and i can read the code! Seriously thanks again!!!!!

Comment: @berni3mack great! I'm glad I could help.